# How to zip 'dist' folder as final build step of ember-cli application

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Is there an easy way to zip the dist folder as part of my ember build?

```
ember build --build=production
```

Are there some hooks that I can use?

Comment: I use grunt for deployment. Its easy to start `ember build --build=production` with grunt, and then do every funny grunt stuff u want. I think your zipping is part of your deployment. So a Task Runner is a good solution. Broccoli and ember-cli for building, grunt for post-build and deployment.

Comment: Good idea.  I guess this is exactly what grunt should be used for.  I got it working in 30 minutes.  Works great!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This used to be something that could be handled in a simple addon using the postBuild hook. However, the point at which this hook is called was recently changed so that it fires before everything is copied into dist. It's understandable that some may need this behaviour but it screws anyone who was relying on the files being in dist already when postBuild is called. I opened an issue about it [here](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/4247) but it doesn't appear to have much movement.

Meanwhile, I do as @anschoewe suggests and use a shell script which calls ember itself, then tends to my postBuild needs.

Comment: Thanks. That confirms my suspicion.  Btw, @alexdiliberto suggested the work around.  I'm torn about who to give the credit to.  You gave a more complete solution, that included alexdiliberto -but thank you both!!

Comment: I'm fine with it going to him. I just wanted to give a bit of background.

Answer (score 0):

I use a `prod_build.sh` file and just run that.

```
$> ./prod_build.sh
```

the script just calls `ember b --environment=production` and zips up the final build contents `zip -r <my_folder>`